# XBAP Application and Remoting - Should I use an SSL Certificate

Tags: .net, security, ssl, xbap

I am considering deploying an existing WPF application as an XBAP application. It currently uses TCP remoting which i would likely change to HTTP remoting. What is the best way to secure the communication - will using an SSL certificate on the remoting server be sufficient or are further steps necessary in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 questions in your question actually:

1. Can I switch my Remoting app to XBAP?
2. How can I secure my Remoting sessions with SSL?

With regards to the first question, note that [you can only use Remoting under the full trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364059(VS.80).aspx#prtltrstpro_topic5) mode, while XBAP applications work under partial trust by default. To enable full trust XBAP you'll have to [go through a painful way of issuing a certificate and installing it](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2008/03/05/wpf-xbap-as-full-trust-application.aspx) to the clients' machines (unless they are all in the same domain and you can create a trusted site in that domain).

With regards to the second question, take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300447.aspx).

Hope it helps.